# Is it possible to get this facebook plugin working with pure phonegap app

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, cordova

This might be really a basic issue. I am kind of confused.  I don't understand one thing. Phonegap app is pure html5 and javascript. But for this plugin (https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/tree/master/example/HackBook) to work we need separate java code for android and xcode for ios.

I got the java version of the android tutorial working with the simulator but when I just copy the assets folder to build a pure phonegap app. it does not work.

Then it beats the purpose if i still have to maintain 2 code lines.

Does just the html and JavaScript code in this plugin is not supported by phonegap app without java or xcode.

Here is my phone gap app. you can download it. https://build.phonegap.com/apps/211586/share

My code in the git repositiry is here

https://bitbucket.org/sunmeet/phonegab2.0_fbapi

Answer (score 0):

**PhoneGap Build service only Supports ChildBrowser , Barcode Scanner, Google Analytics recently.**

if you try to use any external plugin which needs assets other than HTML / CSS / JS, you can't use them with PhoneGap Build Service. But, PhoneGap Team are trying to push out different plugins like Facebook Connect in Future Releases.

So, here they gave two Options to Deveopers.

- Use Child Browser and Do Process Facebook OAuth Authentication.
- Build Locally.
  Andriod developement environment is "Eclipse"  IOS
  developement environment is "XCode"(OS: MacOS)

I Suggest you to work with first option and once plugin is our from build service its really easy to integrate anytime.