# phonegap facebook plugin not working when compiled with build.phonegap.com

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I developed a phonegap application with facebook login integration using "*https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect*". when I run the application using emulator or by connecting real device directly its working fine.

when I built an app (android / ios) using build.phonegap.com neither of the apps are working and throwing an exceptions **"cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on init!"** and **"cordova Facebook Connect plugin fail on auth.Status"**.

so, how can make it work with all platforms supported by phonegap build service.

Here my doubt is

> we are adding plugin reference in plugin.xml in res folder and adding facebook resources in project root in emulator everything is availble and working fine. But, when we build using phonegap build server we are uploading only assets and no where we are adding that plugin packages or plugins.xml.
>
> So, how phonegap build service know how to add native resources in different native builds.

may be my question is duplicate of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008500/is-it-possible-to-get-this-facebook-plugin-working-with-pure-phonegap-app" where no answers found.

Thanks in advance,
Prasad.CH

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get this facebook plugin working with pure phonegap app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008500/is-it-possible-to-get-this-facebook-plugin-working-with-pure-phonegap-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**build.phonegap.com** doesn't complie "**cordova Facebook Connect plugin**" for IPhone or Android. So you can only develope Facebook Connect plugin in native Android and IPhone code.

Andriod developement environment is "**Eclipse**" 
IOS developement environment is "**XCode**"(OS: MacOS)

Comment: Thanks for reply.I understood what you saying,But I would like to know is there any other standard way to get multi-platform native apps  from phone build service. I need alternatives for Facebook connect plugin because I cant compile IOS or windows platforms. Thanks in Advance